# International Ordinals in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails ,

My site is developed in two language english and french , i am using i18n for translation.

i want to use i18n with ordinalize, can any one please help me here.

I went through below link but haven’t got any success

http://murfy.de/read/i18n-ordinalization

http://info.michael-simons.eu/2009/02/12/localizing-dates-and-time-with-rails-i18n-using-procs/

Please guide what exact steps i have to follow.

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and I tried the links you provided, too. However, I couldn't get them work, either. Finally, I thought out a solution:

1) add a new helper method to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def ordinalize_number number
    case I18n.locale
    when :en
        return number.ordinalize
    when :'zh-TW'
        return number
    else
        return number
    end
end
```

2) update your `config/locales/*.yml` (en.yml in this case)

```
end_quarter: 'End The %{order} Quarter'
```

3) use the helper method with default i18n method in your `html.erb`

```
<%= t('end_quarter', :order => ordinalize_number(3)) %>
# it will show "End The 3rd Quarter" properly
```

Although I am not sure whether it's the best solution, it works without changing any environment settings.

Comment: even i did using helper's.. but other method.. dirty method

Answer (score 2):

Ordinalization supports translation as of April 19th 2018:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32168/files

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinal` method has built-in localization for several languages, including English and French:

```
I18n.with_locale(:en) { 1.ordinal } #=> "st"
I18n.with_locale(:fr) { 1.ordinal } #=> "er/ère"
```

So assuming you have `:en` and `:fr` locale keys and cannot or don't want to add new locales for ordinals, the solution also might be as follows:

```
# in a helper or wherever you find convenient
def ordinalize_number(number)
   "#{number}#{number.ordinal}"
end
```